# Wooden drawer repair

Tags: repair, drawers

[image]

After decades of service, the faceplate of the drawer has detached.  The underside had several small nails and staples pinning the plate.

Hopefully, the photos show that the sides of the drawer (particle board) are worn, so as to not be able to accommodate nails from the plate into the sides.

I am considering using a 90 degree angle iron to pin the plate in place.  However, before I do this, I would like to hear how others (if you have performed this repair please indicate in your reply) have repaired / solved this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I agree, slap on a 90° metal bracket and call it a job well done. That drawer has seen better days and I can only assume aestetics are no longer a concern. You might get better input over at the woodworking sister site but I assume they're answer is to just build a new drawer from actual wood.

Comment: Could probably use longer nails/screws, but think your idea is the best.

Answer (score 2):

I would **glue** in corner blocks.   If you nail or screw something in, you could split the wood or go right through it and really ruin it.

[image]

Comment: You should probably clarify on the glue part as to what type. I don't think wood glue is right because there appears to be a vinyl veneer on it; CA glue perhaps.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Good point, maybe they can put a drop of glue on it to test for adherence.   If one glue isn't promising try another.